# Technical capabilities of iBeacon

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon

I am new to beacons, but I am trying to understand the pros and cones of iBeacons for an app on iOS and Android:

I understand that on iOS:

- Apps in the background can monitor for BLE/bluetooth
- Apps in the background can be opened through a local notification which the user can press and thereby open the app.

But this still leaves two important use cases I am unsure about:

1)

When the app is installed, but not running at all, is it possible to have the app launched or at least a message asking to open the app on:

- iOS?
- Android?

2)

If the app is not installed - is it possible to prompt the user to download an app like EddyStone beacons on:

- iOS?
- Android?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when an app is not running, you can detect beacons and have them send notifications to a user on both iOS and Android.  Tapping on the notification will bring the app to the foreground.  There are a couple of platform-specific distinctions:

**Android:** A third party library such as the open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) must be used to trigger background scanning even when the app has not been launched by the user.  (Technically the app is running when doing this scanning, but only the beacon scanning parts of it.)  On an Android device only, you can fully launch the app to the foreground on beacon detection instead of just sending a notification.  Background detection works well with both iBeacon and Eddystone.

**iOS:** Background detection works much more quickly with iBeacon than Eddystone.

**It is not possible to use beacons to prompt users to install your app on iOS using either iBeacon or Eddystone.**

On Android, **it is possible to use Google Nearby to prompt a user to install your app on newer Android 4.4+ devices.**  (This works with both iBeacon and Eddsystone, if you have your beacons properly configured with Google.)   That said, a number of conditions must be satisfied for this to work:

- Google Nearby must be enabled in Google settings
- Location must be enabled
- Bluetooth must be on
- Google Play Services v.10.0 must be installed on the phone (earlier version 9.8 available through November 2016 had Nearby notifications disabled.)  Note that most phones in China and many other countries do not have Google Play Services at all.
- You must register your beacons with google and set up Nearby app intents.

Read more about the basics of Nearby [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview) and more about using App Intents to send users to the Google Play Store to install your app [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format#app_install).

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/22/how-to-push-messages-without-an-app.html